# PHP XML Break Apart Values

Tags: php, xml

I am importing an RSS feed from the NOAA website which is returned as RSS.
The latitude and longitude values are returned as one tag which is below:

```
<georss:point>40.369 -73.703</georss:point>
```

Is it possible to 'break' apart these values and create two variables such as:

```
$lat = 40.369
$lng = -73.703
```

Here is my PHP script that is currently parsing out the XML:

```
$rss_title = $RSS_DOC->channel->title;
$rss_link = $RSS_DOC->channel->link;
$rss_editor = $RSS_DOC->channel->managingEditor;
$rss_copyright = $RSS_DOC->channel->copyright;
$rss_date = $RSS_DOC->channel->item->pubDate;
$rss_description = $RSS_DOC->channel->item->description;
```

Appreciate any resource to get me pointed in the right direction. thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, not too hard. Explode (edited - thanks @sdleihssirhc):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

E.g.:

```
list($latt, $long) = explode(" ", $RSS_DOC->channel->item->point);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: thank you very much! I did not know how 'explode' works... thanks!